# Probability of rain in Tokyo

Tags: probability, puzzle, bayes-theorem

Three friends in Tokyo told you that its rainy. Each person has a probability of 1/4 of lying. What is the probability that it is raining in Tokyo? Assume $Pr(rain)$ in Tokyo = 1/5.

Given options:

A) 4/ 101

B) 4/79

C) 2/91

D) 1/109

In my approach I'm getting ans as 27/31.

Pr(y,y,y | rain) * Pr(rain) / (Pr(y,y,y | rain) * Pr(rain) +
Pr(y,y,y | no_rain) * Pr(no_rain))

= $(3/4)^3 * 1/5\ /\ ((3/4)^3 * 1/5 + (1/4)^3 * (4/5))$

= $27\ /\ 31$

Where I'm doing mistake?

Comment: None of the official answers make sense.  If all $3$ tell you it is raining, the posterior probability that it is raining is obviously higher than $\frac 15$, but none of the possibilities are.

Comment: To reverse engineer the intended problem from the solutions:  The problem should have said "suppose all three friends tell you it is not raining".

Comment: Yes I also feel the same. The given options are wrong.

Comment: As I say, the problem should have read "the friends all tell you it isn't raining."

Comment: Yes then it is coming 1/109

Comment: For the problem as stated, I also arrived at the answer of $~\dfrac{27}{31}.$